# try-catch dependencies in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm relative new to unit tests but I want to start unit testing legacy ASP NET MVC app.
For example I have function PrepareModel that does a lot of things and have multiple dependencies.
I added newFeature to my model and created myNewCode, to get this feature.

```
public Model PrepareModel(){
  Model model = new Model();
  model.mainPropertie = getFromDataBase();
  
  model.someIrrelevantProperty1 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
  model.someIrrelevantProperty2 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
  
  model.newFeature = myNewCode();
  return model;
}
```

**I want to Unit test PrepareModel() that model.newFeature is got correctly.**

I successfully mocked database but there are plenty of irrelevant dependencies. I don't have so much time to refactor out them all.

**Would it be acceptable to add try-catch wrap around features that's irrelevant to test?**
And maybe in future I would refactor them out when there will be next task in this functionality.

```
public static bool isTest { get; set; }
public Model PrepareModel(){
  Model model = new Model();
  model.mainPropertie = getFromDataBase();
  
  try{
    model.someIrrelevantProperty1 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
    model.someIrrelevantProperty2 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
  } 
  catch(Exception ex) {
    if (!isTest)
      throw ex;
  }
  
  model.newFeature = myNewCode();
  return model;
}
```

If that's not acceptable what should I do?

Comment: What happens when at some other point an exception is thrown at these two lines? You won't realize and your program continues running with inconsistent data. For me, that wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: Changing the SuT to be testable is - sometimes needed - but allways cumbersome and you should avoid it as much as possible. Instead try to write more coarse-grained tests that also include the depencies in the first run, even if thpose aren´t actual **unit**-test you have at least **some** level of automatic testing.

Comment: There is no reall whrong or right answer here. It really depends on what you want to achieve with the test.

Comment: I want to start adding unit tests somewhere and gradually increase code coverage. 
But I don't know where to start. 
I recently added new feature and I thought it would be easy to test it, but my tests failed by endless run time errors.

Comment: @SomeBody Thanks. I updated example that out of test exception wouldn't be lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better approach to do that.
Look, that you have made your `isTest` variable public - this is dangerous. The better solution for that problem, would be to create new configuration in your solution and call it TEST. Next in your test app just add TEST to defines. And in your code:

```
public Model PrepareModel(){
  Model model = new Model();
  model.mainPropertie = getFromDataBase();
  
#if !TEST
  model.someIrrelevantProperty1 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
  model.someIrrelevantProperty2 = getValueFromSomeDependency();
#endif
  
  model.newFeature = myNewCode();
  return model;
}
```

Of course, this assumes that test would only be running in TEST configuration*

If you don't know what I mean by "configuration" it's just another one beside DEBUG and RELEASE.